# finding maximum number of users in department

Tags: subnet

I have the next issue :
A company has the network ID:192.168.10.0/24 , the company is composed of 10 department. What is the maximum number of the users in each department that can be covered by this address space ?

i need to know the way of finding the maximum users step by step in order to finding the solution fot other issues

Comment: You need to clarify your question: it is that space only for users??, you don' t need to put on this network services like servers, printers?, it is this network connected directly into a router or L3 switch?, do your network need to reach the internet or is completely isolated?

Comment: to be honest ... it's an exam question ... it is as like this and nothing more 
I can tell it depends on subneting ... I don't know what to do !!
only a company with 10 departments !!

Comment: Your question is out of topic here i guess, no matter of that i will give you an answer

Comment: [This post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) should help you out. Hint: you cannot divide a /24 in to 10 equal sized subnets. Expect some wasted space.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: it's question  year ago exam ... i'm not trying to cheat !! and it may issue in real work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 192.168.10.0/24 and 10 departments:

Firts, i will suppose that you don' t have any requirement about your address space, because i will give you the basic answer.

What you need to do its subnetting looking 10 different networks>

You need to remember that there is a rule for that: (2^n) where n is the number of bits
If you take 3 bits:  8 networks, NOT
If you take 4 bits: 16 networks, YES

192.168.10.0000 0000    the last octet it is in bit notation

192.168.10.**0000** 0000

192.168.10.**0001** 0000

192.168.10.**0010** 0000

192.168.10.**0011** 0000

192.168.10.**0100** 0000

192.168.10.**0101** 0000

192.168.10.**0110** 0000

192.168.10.**0111** 0000

192.168.10.**1000** 0000

192.168.10.**1001** 0000

192.168.10.**1010** 0000

192.168.10.**1011** 0000

192.168.10.**1100** 0000

192.168.10.**1101** 0000

192.168.10.**1110** 0000

192.168.10.**1111** 0000

The part of the octet that i has  write in bold form, that bits now will be part of network, and ther your mask will move to 28.

On that way, you have your 10 required networks and 6 networks more.

Then your network will have 2^n -2 host, cause the first address is your networks address and the last is your broadcast address. Every network will have then 14 hosts.

Comment: thank you ... so there is no need for the address to be addressed exactly 10 partitions ...?

Comment: Oh no, for do that, you need to do VLSM, where ones department will be more address like other, but you will use more wisely your address space. That is not a easy method and you need to practice a lot